# Entity Admin Fields UI enbabling

Tags: 7, entities

how can I enable fields for an entity in the admin ui?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You can give the user an interface for fields for a entity record, right?

Comment: Yep. But what do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know how I can enable this for my entity class. For example what url patterns do I need or something like that. Since I am new to Drupal I don't know much about it. And I am working on a already existing website.

Comment: There aren't any rules for URL patterns (couldn't comment on "something like that" obviously, that could mean anything). You're best bet would be to go through the Entity module in [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), that has all the code you need in it, most should just be a copy/paste job